Annotations are not enlarged on tap gesture in MapKit SwiftUI
I have written a MapView in SwiftUI which shows different locations. What i want is that when the user taps on any location then that location should be enlarged whihc means "mappin.and.ellipse.circle.fill" should enlarged. Secondly, that location in the Vstack should be selected by changing background to orange.
Below is my code:
struct MapView: View {
    var selectedText: String
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 49.142691, longitude: 9.210920),
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
        )
        
    @State private var selectedPlace: Place?

    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: getLocations(for: selectedText)) { place in
            MapAnnotation(coordinate: place.coordinate) {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "mappin.and.ellipse.circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: selectedPlace?.id == place.id ? 50 : 30, height: selectedPlace?.id == place.id ? 50 : 30)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectPlace(place)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 300)
        .padding(.top)
        
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(getLocations(for: selectedText)) { place in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                        Text(place.name)
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text(place.address)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                        Button(action: {
                            //openMaps(for: place)
                        }) {
                            Text("Show Directions")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(selectedPlace?.id == place.id ? Color(.systemOrange) : Color(.systemGray6))
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .onTapGesture 
                    {
                        selectPlace(place)
                        //region.center = place.coordinate
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        HStack {
            Button("Back") {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
            .cornerRadius(8)
        }
 
    }
    private func selectPlace(_ place: Place) {
        withAnimation {
                   selectedPlace = place
                   region.center = place.coordinate
               }
        }


OK, so you described what you want, but what is the problem? What is and what is not working?

Now, when i click on the location, nothing happens it only centres in the Map. But nothing is selcted and the annotations are not enlarged.

I know absolutely nothing about swiftui, but shouldn't the View be rendered anew after assigning a value to SelectedPlace? If that is supposed to be done automatically by withAnimation please excuse my ignorance.

I recommend to watch the WWDC 2023 video "Meet MapKit for SwiftUI".

What iOS version are you supporting? Can you use the new MapKit API in iOS 17?

I solved it. The problem was that somehow the id was not getting updated in the below line:
.frame(width: selectedPlace?.id == place.id ? 50 : 30, height: selectedPlace?.id == place.id ? 50 : 30)

So, i changed it to:
.frame(width: selectedPlace?.name == place.name ? 50 : 30, height: selectedPlace?.name == place.name ? 50 : 30)

Now, it is working fine. Now, when i click on the location it is becoming enlarged and blue in colour.
